# Flutter increase container height in a grid view

Tags: flutter

I am using a grid view i need to show a 3x3 container. The issue is i am not able to set the height of the container it's not increasing and cut the content.

My code

```
Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: new TextSpan(
                            // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                            // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Service ',
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 22)),
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Deals',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: Width * 0.1,
                          height: Height * 0.05,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/see.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),


                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    child: GridView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(

                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.025,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/heartfill.png'),

                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.025,
                                      color: Color(0xffD4E6F1),
                                      child: Image.asset('images/add.png'),

                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: Height * 0.11,
                                  child: Image.asset('images/hp.png'),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        child: Text('\$45'),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            height: Height * 0.02,
                                            child: Image.asset('images/star.png'),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text('4.4'),
                                          )

                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

I need to achieve this type of boxes

[image]

I have done something similar but its cropping the content i need to increase the height of my container Here is whats the issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use childAspectRatio property of SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount to set the ratio of the cross-axis to the main-axis extent of each child.
for ex

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        childAspectRatio:0.8
                      ),
```

It is actually the width to height ratio for child of grid view.Adjust it accordingly.